# Internet Explorer 7 textarea field and dropdown fields

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

We have a client who is using IE7 and for some reason drop-down boxes and text-area area fields are not displaying correctly.  The arrow for the drop-down box does not appear and the right border of the text-area box does not display.

Works in IE 8/9, Chrome, FF.  **See image attached**[image]

Does anyone know what is causing this and how I can fix?

This is a html/php app

Comment: When in doubt, add a `zoom:1;` property for these items in your CSS.

Comment: Hi All, sorry migration time a work, finally back to this.  I added zoom, but I don't see any effect in IE7.  I did get a laptop that still has IE7 on it so I can test myself now.  here is the code that renders the textarea field and where I added the zoom: `case FIELD_TEXT_AREA:
    $fieldHtml = inputOrText($mode, "textarea", $field->getValue(), array("id"=>$field->getId(), "class"=>"valuetext", "name"=>$field->getId(), "rows"=>"3","cols"=>"60", $jsFunctionCalls), array("class"=>"valuetext", "zoom"=>"150%"));`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include the markup so we can only guess. There is no way to know for sure. I would inspect the textboxes in Firebug or something similar and see if they're inheriting styles that you aren't aware of.

Comment: Here is the code that would make up a textara and dropdown field: '<textarea id="201" class="valuetext" name="201" rows="3" cols="60" 0=""> </textarea>

<select id="19" name="19" class="valuetext fld-3-19-required" onchange="projectTypeChange()">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="Banner"> Banner </option>
<option value="Email"> Email </option>
<option value="Flyer"> Flyer </option>
<option value="Not There"> Not There </option>
<option value="Post Card"> Post Card </option>
</select>'